# Would like to doublecheck that I created a TXT SPF record correctly for multiple IP addresses

Tags: spf, txt-record

I currently have this TXT SPF record:

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:173.9.41.65 ~all
```

That above record is only supposed to allow that IP address to send.  However, I now have 5 static IPs that need to be allowed (173.9.41.65 – 173.9.41.69 let’s say) and also want to turn the soft fail for “all” into a hard fail; what I’m trying to do is fail everything that’s not from the 5 ip addresses

I believe the following pseudo-syntax is what I need.  I also removed the "a" and "mx" because I believe they are extraneous, but please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
v=spf ip4:[IPADDRESSESHERE] –all
```

However, I'm not sure of the best/shortest way to include all 5 of those IP addresses in the record.  Am I able to do this for a valid SPF syntax?:

```
v=spf ip4:173.9.41.65 ip4:173.9.41.66 ip4:173.9.41.67 ip4:173.9.41.68 ip4:173.9.41.69 –all
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, or you can do CIDR notation. `ip4:173.9.41.64/29` would cover all of those IPs.

Comment: Further to what ceejayoz said you can also check your syntax online once you've published it. eg http://emailstuff.org/spf and http://mxtoolbox.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an SPF record can include CIDR notation:

```
v=spf1 ip4:173.9.41.64/29 -all
```

The `a` and `mx` mechanisms as used in your previous record result in receiving servers accepting mail from the IP address or addresses of the records of the domain. If those addresses are in the addresses already in the record, then including the mechanisms would be redundant.